# What is the difference between ConfigureWebHostDefaults and ConfigureWebHost methods?

Tags: .net-core

I see 2 nearly the same extension methods on generic host builder class (`HostBuilder`): `ConfigureWebHostDefaults` and `ConfigureWebHost`. They have the same signature and locate in different assemblies. I saw `ConfigureWebHostDefaults` in guides but there is nearly nothing about `ConfigureWebHost`. What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Via ASP.NET Core source code, `ConfigureWebHostDefaults` equals to:

```cs
        public static IHostBuilder ConfigureWebHostDefaults(this IHostBuilder builder, Action<IWebHostBuilder> configure)
        {
            return builder.ConfigureWebHost(webHostBuilder =>
            {
                WebHost.ConfigureWebDefaults(webHostBuilder);

                configure(webHostBuilder);
            });
        }
```

It just calls the `ConfigureWebHost`, but will an additional step: `ConfigureWebDefaults`.

As for `ConfigureWebDefaults`, the source code is pretty long and placed here:

https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/1480b998660d2f77d0605376eefab6a83474ce07/src/DefaultBuilder/src/WebHost.cs#L280

For the difference, `ConfigureWebHostDefaults` configures a web host with:

- Use Kestrel as the web server and configure it using the application's configuration providers
- Adds the HostFiltering middleware,
- Adds the ForwardedHeaders middleware if ASPNETCORE_FORWARDEDHEADERS_ENABLED=true,
- Enable IIS integration.

Also, the official document mentioned that:

> The ConfigureWebHostDefaults method loads host configuration from environment variables prefixed with "ASPNETCORE_".
>   Sets Kestrel server as the web server and configures it using the app's hosting configuration providers. For the Kestrel server's default options, see Kestrel web server implementation in ASP.NET Core.
>   Adds Host Filtering middleware.
>   Adds Forwarded Headers middleware if ASPNETCORE_FORWARDEDHEADERS_ENABLED=true.
>   Enables IIS integration. For the IIS default options, see Host ASP.NET Core on Windows with IIS.

Document link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-3.0#default-builder-settings

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer!