# ASP.NET Core startup message log

Tags: c#, asp.net, kestrel-http-server

I have an ASP.NET Core 3.1 app, which was upgraded from ASP.NET Core 2.0. We would like to get the old startup messages ("Now listening on: http://localhost:5000", etc) to log through the configured structured logging options. This works out of the box with new 3.1 projects, but I cannot figure out how to enable it in an existing project that does not use the `ConfigureWebHostDefaults()` method at startup. For example, this logs startup through structured logging:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
}

public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        });
```

But this doesn't:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseKestrel()
        .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
        {
            logging.AddDebug();
            logging.AddConsole();
        })
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .Build()
        .Run();
}
```

I found this question:

[What is the difference between ConfigureWebHostDefaults and ConfigureWebHost methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58905731/what-is-the-difference-between-configurewebhostdefaults-and-configurewebhost-met)

and scanned through the code linked there, but I'm coming up blank. What's the magic incantation to connect Kestrel to the logging infrastructure?

Comment: if it works as expected in out-of-box core 3.1, why not upgrade  startup implementation to it from 2.0 as well ?

Comment: Because our startup implementation is more complex than the out of the box version with custom logging providers, config, etc

Comment: You can use ConfigureLogging with CreateDefaultBuilder: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60151374/1043380, so you can use that to add/remove logging sinks and custom ones

Comment: I'm using your second code block in a 3.1 app, and I can't reproduce the issue. I do see "now listening on ...." in the console.

Comment: It does get output, it just doesn't get formatted by the logger. It's a straight Console.Write()

Comment: look at the `appsettings.json` for the logging section

Comment: @gunr2171 I tried that originally, and ended up with two loggers outputting, but I missed the `ClearProviders()` step in ConfigureLogging. Feel free to drop that in an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: I'm going to decline, as I'm really not sure why that worked for you :D. Go head and self answer so I can learn something as well.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, we just needed to fully switch over to the new host builder (`CreateHostBuilder` vs the older `CreateWebHostBuilder`). We had tried it before, but when we added our custom logging provider in `ConfigureLogging` we ended up with duplicated log messages, so we rolled back to the old way without fully understanding the difference. The missing bit was calling `ClearProviders()`. Before, we had:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
}

public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) => WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseKestrel()
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) => { ... }))
    .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
    {
        logging.AddConfiguration(hostingContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));

        logging.AddProvider(new CustomLoggerProvider());
        logging.AddDebug();
    })
    .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

And now:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
     CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
}

public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) => Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) => { ... } ))
    .ConfigureLogging((hostBuilder, logging) =>
    {                
        logging.ClearProviders();

        logging.AddConfiguration(hostBuilder.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));

        logging.AddProvider(new CustomLoggerProvider());
        logging.AddDebug();
    })
    .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
    {
        webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
    });
```

Now Kestrel nicely logs it's status messages to the preferred logger along with everything else.